# Можно ли так сказать?

Tags: употребление-слов

феерия жизни

Answer (score 1):

ФЕЕРИЯ  1. Театральное  или  цирковое представление сказочного  содержания отличающееся пышной  постановкой и сценическими эффектами  (спец.). 2. перен.  Волшебное, сказочное зрелище (книжн.).

Если воспринимать жизнь как сказочное, волшебное зрелище, то сочетание "феерия жизни" возможно. Но если "феерия жизни" - это практическая магия, различные духовные практики, то такое выражение не слишком удачно.

В этом случае искажается суть названия, так как мы уже не считаем слово "феерия" тропом, а придаем ему прямое значение, в то время как оно обычно используется именно в переносном смысле.